# Bootstrap element hiding issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap form with several repeating elements, making it quite long. I was wanting to hide these with an "Add Another?" option to show the next one, and so on.

I am using the bootstrap switch on the field to select "adding another", and then display the next tab, and the following code is accomplishing this:

I started with this to show or hide the tab:

```
var add2 = getFormTabByIndex(4);

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#add2ndfield').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e, data) {
    var state = $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');
    if (state) {
        $(add2).prop('hidden', false);
    } else {
        $(add2).prop('hidden', true);
    }
});
});
```

But on a new form, the tab was showing by default. So I added this to hide the tab initially on load:

```
$(add2).prop('hidden', true);
```

This works just they way I want on a new form, but when the form is saved and reopened, all tabs are of course hidden again because on the above line, duh.

I need any tabs a user previously elected, to be displayed on a form reload. So I replaced the first part, that hides it on load, with this, to first check the state:

```
var state2 = $('#add2ndfield').is(':checked');
if (state2) {
$(add2).prop('hidden', false);
} else {
$(add2).prop('hidden', true);
}
```

It is not working, and I am chasing my tail, any thoughts?

My Jquery skills are limited to cut/paste/edit until something works :-)

Comment: Shouldn't state2 also be

    `var state2 = $(this).bootstrapSwitch('state');`

Comment: Please attach js fiddle.

Comment: Here is my attempt at a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Fworks/mrnL3770/10/

Comment: I am not sure how to simulate reloading a form in a fiddle

Comment: phreakv6 I am sure you are right, I am not sure how to write it like that without the switchChange event. In this case, the switch would not be changing, so I did not know how to trigger it.